# Unable to see supporting files after a NUGET (Xamarin.UItest.POP) package is installed

Tags: c#, xamarin, automation, ui-automation, xamarin.uitest

Installed the Xamarin.UItest.POP Nuget package and according to the documentation mentioned here I am supposed to see four supporting files but I cannot see them in my UI test project.

```
Files that I expect to see :
AppManager.cs
BaseTestFixture.cs
BasePage.cs
PlatformQuery.cs
```

Documentation referred:https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/best-practices-tips-xamarin-uitest

I've reinstalling it and updating all my nuget packages but still unable to see those files

Would appreciate some help as I am pretty new to creating a framework for Xamarin UI automation.

Comment: NuGet packages can no longer deploy content to your project (that nuget is from 2017). Just copy the four files from the github sample that is linked in the blog post.

Comment: Okay makes sense, thanks for the info!